# Kendo Tooltip closes when mouse enters the tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

These are the options I am using for the tooltip

```
{                
  filter: '.k-event',
  position: 'top',
  width: 220,
  content: Template_Name.html()),
  showOn: 'mouseenter',
  autoHide: true
}
```

I have a fixed height and a vertical scroll for the tooltip using this overide

```
.k-tooltip-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

The tooltip is set over Kendo calendar event. The calendar loads the events and when user hovers over the event the tooltip is shown. The problem I am facing is when the mouse leaves the event area the tooltip goes away. So the user cannot scroll the tooltip.
I have tried the  `autoHide: true` option butits not the desired behavior.

Comment: The `autoHide` configuration specifies if the tooltip will be hidden when the mouse leaves the target element. Set it to `false` and the tooltip should remain visible - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/uRoZaDOj)

Comment: @Aleksandar In your demo if I change the ```autohide``` to ```true``` I am still able to go onto the tooltip itself without it disappearing. This is what I want https://dojo.telerik.com/UzujATIH

Comment: I don't get it - do you want to tooltip to remain visible when you leave the event area fin order to scroll it's content or to disappear? Setting the `autoHide` to true will add a `X` button for the use to close the tooltip, but it will remain visible when you leave the event area. You can also hide that button so the tooltip will remain visible. You will have to hover on another event or click somewhere to close the tooltip - https://dojo.telerik.com/EFuyAbiP